# Get Cell From Range

Tags: excel, countif

I am putting together a spreadsheet for my local soccer competition and am trying to autofill some cells.

I have one sheet with all the teams, players and their stats in it and then another sheet which has all the goals. The sheet with all the goals also has a column for team name and player name.

The aim is to when I type in the player name in the goals for it to check if the name matches in the other sheet and get the team name from that row.

I am using the following formula to see if the name matches but I do not know how to make this formula return the team name from the other cell in that row. I can make it return yes or no etc but do not know how to get the value of the cell.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Teams!C:C, Goals!A2), "", "N/A")
```

If someone could help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Teams!C:C,MATCH(Goals!A2,Teams!C:C,0)),"N/A")
```

Change the column reference in INDEX(Teams!C:C with the column from which you want to return the value if Goals!A2 is found in Teams!C:C.

So if you want to return the value from column D e.g., try the above formula like this...

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Teams!D:D,MATCH(Goals!A2,Teams!C:C,0)),"N/A")
```